# Como setar os dados de um DataGrid para um TextBox em C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando setar os dados da linha selecionada do DataGrid, que vem do B.D., para mostrar em cada TextBox. O dado de cada coluna da linha selecionada vai para um TextBox. Como faço? Qual método utilizar?

```
namespace EstoquePeca
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtPeca.Focus();
    }
    //Consultar Todos
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection aConnection = new    OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/estoque.mdb");
        OleDbCommand aCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from ESTOQUEPECA", aConnection);
        aConnection.Open();
        var Consulta = aCommand.ExecuteReader();

        GridDados.ItemsSource = Consulta;

        GridDados.Columns[0].Header = "Código";
        GridDados.Columns[1].Header = "Quantidade";
        GridDados.Columns[2].Header = "Descrição";
        GridDados.Columns[3].Header = "Alternativo 1";
        GridDados.Columns[4].Header = "Alternativo 2";
    }
    //Consultar pelo código
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "select * from ESTOQUEPECA WHERE COD ='" + txtPeca.Text + "'";
        OleDbConnection aConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/estoque.mdb");
        OleDbCommand aCommand = new OleDbCommand(sql, aConnection);
        aConnection.Open();
        var Consulta = aCommand.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            if (txtPeca.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Digite o código da Peça!");
            }
            else
            {
                GridDados.ItemsSource = Consulta;
                GridDados.Columns[0].Header = "Código";
                GridDados.Columns[1].Header = "Quantidade";
                GridDados.Columns[2].Header = "Descrição";
                GridDados.Columns[3].Header = "Alternativo 1";
                GridDados.Columns[4].Header = "Alternativo 2";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AtualizaPeca ap = new AtualizaPeca();
        ap.Show();
    }
    //Seta os dados no textbox
    private void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AtualizaPeca ap = new AtualizaPeca();
        ap.Show();
        ap.txtCodigo.Text = GridDados.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: O que já fez? Pode colocar um pouco do seu código fonte? Assim conseguimos entender o que já foi feito, e auxiliá-lo melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Eu passei por uma situação parecida em um projeto, porém nela cada registro do meu *DataGridView* representava um objeto de uma classe específica. 
Você pode criar um método *CellContentClick* e nele recuperar o valor da célula clicada e/ou os valores do mesmo registro. Segue um exemplo:

```
    private void meuGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // Recupera o valor da célula clicada.
        textBox.Text = meuGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
        // Obtém um objeto a partir da linha da célula clicada.
        objMinhaClasse = meuGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as MinhaClasse;
    }
```

Comment: Vou seguir esse exemplo, acho que consigo uma solução. Obrigado por enquanto!

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz isso há pouco tempo atrás..

A diferença é que eu varria o `DataGridView` inteiro e não é esse seu problema, certo?
Pelo o que eu entendi você quer clicar em uma linha e recuperar o valor desta... estou certo?

Se sim, utilize o evento que o "Maniero" mostrou no post acima com algo parecido com isso:

```
DataGridViewCell valor = null;
valor = linha.Cells["colValor"];
```

Onde `"colValor"` é **uma** das colunas que você quer recuperar os dados.

Feito isso, tente algo como `TextBox txtValor = valor.Value.ToString();`

Eu acho que aí da certo! =)

Repita esse procedimento para todas as colunas que você quiser recuperar os valores.

E sim, essa é a mesma implementação do "Maniero", mas eu acho que declarar uma DataGridViewCell ajuda bastante para você ler o código.. Sei lá rsrs.

Edit:
A `linha` você recupera com `DataGridViewRow linha = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex]`, onde `e` é um dos argumentos recebidos pelo evento `CellContentClick`, conforme citado pelo "Maniero".

Answer (score 0):

Estava fazendo um sistema de cadastro de serviços e tive que atribuir todos valores que estavam no grid para os textbox's, então quando eu clico em um grid, ele preenche todos os TextBox's. Recomendo a você que utilize o Evento MouseDoubleClick da DataGrid.
Pode serguir esse exemplo

```
    TextBox.Text = DataGridView..CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataListar_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.txtIdUsuario.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dataListar.CurrentRow.Cells["idUsuario"].Value);
            this.txtNomeUsuario.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dataListar.CurrentRow.Cells["nomeUsuario"].Value);            
            this.txtLoginUsuario.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dataListar.CurrentRow.Cells["loginUsuario"].Value);
            this.txtSenhaUsuario.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dataListar.CurrentRow.Cells["senhaUsuario"].Value);
            this.cbNivelAcesso.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dataListar.CurrentRow.Cells["nivelAcesso"].Value);
            this.cbSituacao.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dataListar.CurrentRow.Cells["situacaoUsuario"].Value);
            this.txtDataUsuario.Text = Convert.ToString(this.dataListar.CurrentRow.Cells["dataUsuario"].Value);

            this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
```